# Merging multi csv files that are formated

Tags: python, csv

I am fairly new to this.

I am trying to find a way to merge 2 or more csv files. The problem is they have a custom header and a area to do a total.

The top sort of looks like this

```
Invoice Number, 12345
Issue Date, 2-Dec-13
Credit, 1234

date, job no, sender name, etc, etc1, etc2, etc3

1, 2, A, B, C, D, E
1, 2, A, B, C, D, E
,,,,,total, 100
```

The amount of data changes in each document. Is it possible to merge this header information into 1 complete document or how could i go about removing all the extra header and footer content before i merge?

**Edit**
I'm using

```
import csv

with open("inv1.csv", "rb") as infile, open("inv2", "wb") as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    p = 0
    while p < 11:
        next(reader, None)
        p = p + 1
    f = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in reader:
        f.writerow(row)
```

Ok this is what i have learned so far...

Comment: You have to read on this: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html and then have to write your own logic to do so for merging different headers. To remove headers, you still need to read the way you can access the csv file lines and then do away.

Comment: Please clarify: is the header always of the same length and format? Are there always the same number of fields in the CSV data? Is "total" line always the last one?

Comment: The header info will always be the same format. Same with the footer. The data will be varying lengths.

Comment: Im thinking i can do what i did to the bottom what i did to the top. What i think i need to do is look at the lines and see if there is content on it and then write. When i get to bottom i should be able to use the next() again?